# Interact with Google's My Maps

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, google-maps-markers

I created an own map with [Google's My Maps](https://www.google.com/mymaps). I made a new layer and placed some markers on it.
Is it possible to interact with those markers?

What I want to do "iterating" over those markers in chronological order.
Consider the following map: [Remote Islands of the World](https://www.google.com/maps/d/viewer?mid=1OVDo2UhsRhXKfpNc1TD0K3UCGbM).
I would make a button "Next" on my website. Whenever the user clicks the button, the maps jumps from "Bouvet Island" to "St Helena", after another click it jumps to "Izu Islands - Miyakejima" etc.

I don't even know if it's possible or where to find more information about how to achieve it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One option would be to create a Google Maps Javascript API v3 map and access the KML data from MyMaps using a third party KML parser (like [geoxml3](https://github.com/geocodezip/geoxml3)) through a proxy.

[example](http://www.geocodezip.com/geoxml3_test/v3_geoxml3_kmztest_linktoB.html?forcezip=y&filename=http://www.geocodezip.com/binProxy160404kmz.asp?http://www.google.com/maps/d/kml?mid=1OVDo2UhsRhXKfpNc1TD0K3UCGbM&forcekml=1) (displays the KML point names in the sidebar using geoxml3, but could be modified to add a "next" button that sequences through them).

[example with "next"/"previous" links in infowindow and next button above the map](http://www.geocodezip.com/geoxml3_test/v3_geoxml3_kmztest_linktoB_next.html?forcezip=y&filename=http://www.geocodezip.com/binProxy160404kmz.asp?http://www.google.com/maps/d/kml?mid=1OVDo2UhsRhXKfpNc1TD0K3UCGbM&forcekml=1)

Added this code inside the `useTheData` function (and equivalents for polygons and polylines):

```
if (placemark.marker) {
  google.maps.event.addListener(placemark.marker, 'click', function(i) {

    return function(evt) {
    // add next and previous links to infowindow when the placemark is clicked
    infowindow.setContent(infowindow.getContent()+"<br><a href='javascript:next("+i+");'>next</a>&nbsp;-&nbsp;<a href='javascript:prev("+i+");'>previous</a>");
    // track the last opened placemark 
    openInfoWindow = i;
  }}(i));
```

Then these functions to open the next infowindow:

```
function next(i) {
  var next = (i+1) % geoXmlDoc.placemarks.length;
  if (geoXmlDoc.placemarks[next].marker) {
   google.maps.event.trigger(geoXmlDoc.placemarks[next].marker, "click");
  } else if (geoXmlDoc.placemarks[next].polyline) {
   google.maps.event.trigger(geoXmlDoc.placemarks[next].polyline, "click");
  } else if (geoXmlDoc.placemarks[next].polygon) {
   google.maps.event.trigger(geoXmlDoc.placemarks[next].polygon, "click");
  }
}
function nextBtn() {
  // handle case where button is clicked before any placemarks on the map
  if (!openInfoWindow) openInfoWindow = 0;
  next(openInfoWindow);     
}
```

Note that because geoxml3 uses XmlHttpRequest to access the data, a proxy must be used on the domain displaying the page to overcome the same domain restriction on XmlHttpRequest.